# Código na página principal

Tags: bug, status-pronto, layout

Como mostrado [pelo @MarceloBoni](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36549573#36549573) no chat, a página inicial está mostrando código fonte (um `RenderPartial()`), como mostrado na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Também está aparecendo no [SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), [Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) e outros sites da rede.
>
> P.S.: Somente para usuários logados.

Acho que alguém esqueceu do `@` antes, :p.

Comment: No meta também está assim.

Comment: HAHAHAHAHAHA, parece eu =D